# Ubuntu 16.04: Internal mic not working, headphones not automatically detected, trackpad not working

Tags: touchpad, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

I just go a new laptop and installed ubuntu 16.04. However, I already 
have quite a few problems. 
1) The internal microphone isn't working.
2) Headphones aren't detected automatically when plugged in.
3) Two finger scrolling doesn't work.

For problem 1, I have tried playing around with alsamixer and unmutting the output but nothing changed. For problem 2, I installed pulseaudio and can select headphones as an output option to use headphones, but if I don't do this the headphones won't be detected if they are simply plugged in. For problem 3, I have also tried installing focaltech-dkms however I don't think the drivers can be found with xenial.

I tried uninstalling ubuntu 16.04 and installing ubuntu 14.04 hoping the problems would be fixed. However, the installation process kept freezing at the beginning.

I have an Asus EeeBook E402 and these are some specs
 Memory: 7.7 GiB
 Processor Intel® Pentium(R) CPU N3710 @ 1.60GHz × 4 
 Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics (Cherryview)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

go into terminal {CTRL ALT T}  and type Sudo apt-get upgrade and install all of your patches than go to your drivers menu and install any extra drivers and reboot.

if that doesnt help have you tried clicking on sound, sound options than go input and click your microphone.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

I have tried to sudo apt-get upgrade but nothing changed. And I couldn't find any additional drivers to install either. 
I can see the microphone in the sound settings and the input volume is at 100% but the input level has zeros bars.